# How can I use a variable as an index inside of an object? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing

I am trying to use the variables appetizer, main, and dessert as indexes to an array but I cannot figure out how to do this. This is on line 49.

```
    var menu = {
  _courses: {
    appetizers: [],
    mains: [],
    desserts: []
  },
get appetizers() {
   return this._courses.appetizers;
},
get mains() {
  return this._courses.mains;
},
get desserts() {
  return this._courses.desserts;
},
set appetizers(appetizers) {
    this.courses.desserts = desserts;
  },
set mains(mains) {
   this.mains = mains;
},
set desserts(desserts) {
     this.desserts = desserts;
  },
  get courses() {
    return {
      appetizers,
      mains,
      desserts,
    };
  },
  addDishToCourse (courseName, dishName, dishPrice) { 
   const dish = {
     food: courseName,
     name: dishName,
     price: dishPrice,

   };
  return this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
  },
     getRandomDishFromCourse: function(courseName) {
    var dishes = this._courses[courseName];
     if (dishes !== undefined) {
       var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
      return randomIndex;
     }
  },

  generateRandomMeal: function() { //This is the problem.
   var appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    var main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
    var dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('dessert');
    return 'Your meal is ' + appetizer + ', ' + main + ', and ' + dessert + '. The total price is $' +/* this.dish.price */ 8 + '.'; 
  }
}; 

menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Bread Loaf', 4.25);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Caesar Salad', 3.50);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Small Soup', 4.50);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Steak Dinner', 20.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'spaghetti', 16.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Turkey Dinner', 18.99);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Icecream', 5.99);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Cookies', 5.99);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Jello', 5.99);


var meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();
console.log(meal);
```

I have tried to use this code:

```
this.appetizers[appetizer]
this.mains[main]
this.desserts[dessert]
```

but this just returns Object object in place of the index number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getRandomDishFromCourse` selects a random index fom the passed `courseName`, but it only returns the index - it should return a dish object instead, via `return dishes[randomIndex];`.

Once the dish is returned, in `generateRandomMeal`, you need to select each dish's `name` property for printing, and add up all `price`s to get to the total price:

```
  getRandomDishFromCourse: function(courseName) {
    var dishes = this._courses[courseName];
    if (dishes !== undefined) {
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
      return dishes[randomIndex];
    }
  },

  generateRandomMeal: function() { //This is the problem.
    var appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    var main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
    var dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
    return 'Your meal is ' + appetizer.name + ', ' + main.name + ', and ' + dessert.name +
      '. The total price is $' + (appetizer.price + main.price + dessert.price).toFixed(2)
  }
```

```js
var menu = {
  _courses: {
    appetizers: [],
    mains: [],
    desserts: []
  },
  get appetizers() {
    return this._courses.appetizers;
  },
  get mains() {
    return this._courses.mains;
  },
  get desserts() {
    return this._courses.desserts;
  },
  set appetizers(appetizers) {
    this.courses.desserts = desserts;
  },
  set mains(mains) {
    this.mains = mains;
  },
  set desserts(desserts) {
    this.desserts = desserts;
  },
  get courses() {
    return {
      appetizers,
      mains,
      desserts,
    };
  },
  addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
    const dish = {
      food: courseName,
      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice,

    };
    return this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
  },
  getRandomDishFromCourse: function(courseName) {
    var dishes = this._courses[courseName];
    if (dishes !== undefined) {
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
      return dishes[randomIndex];
    }
  },

  generateRandomMeal: function() { //This is the problem.
    var appetizer = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers');
    var main = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains');
    var dessert = this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts');
    return 'Your meal is ' + appetizer.name + ', ' + main.name + ', and ' + dessert.name +
      '. The total price is $' + (appetizer.price + main.price + dessert.price).toFixed(2)
  }
};

menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Bread Loaf', 4.25);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Caesar Salad', 3.50);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Small Soup', 4.50);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Steak Dinner', 20.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'spaghetti', 16.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Turkey Dinner', 18.99);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Icecream', 5.99);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Cookies', 5.99);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Jello', 5.99);


var meal = menu.generateRandomMeal();
console.log(meal);
```

(the `toFixed(2)` is needed after the total to avoid floating-point problems)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use indices to access items in Arrays.  The way you have it now will just print the random indices.

```js
var menu = {
  _courses: {
    appetizers: [],
    mains: [],
    desserts: []
  },
  get appetizers() {
    return this._courses.appetizers;
  },
  get mains() {
    return this._courses.mains;
  },
  get desserts() {
    return this._courses.desserts;
  },
  set appetizers(appetizers) {
    this.courses.desserts = desserts;
  },
  set mains(mains) {
    this.mains = mains;
  },
  set desserts(desserts) {
    this.desserts = desserts;
  },
  get courses() {
    return {
      appetizers: this.appetizers,
      mains: this.mains,
      desserts: this.desserts,
    };
  },
  addDishToCourse(courseName, dishName, dishPrice) {
    const dish = {
      food: courseName,
      name: dishName,
      price: dishPrice,

    };
    return this._courses[courseName].push(dish);
  },
  getRandomDishFromCourse: function(courseName) {
    var dishes = this._courses[courseName];
    if (dishes !== undefined) {
      var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * dishes.length);
      return randomIndex;
    }
  },

  generateRandomMeal: function() { //This is the problem.
    var appetizer = this.appetizers[this.getRandomDishFromCourse('appetizers')];
    var main = this.mains[this.getRandomDishFromCourse('mains')];
    var dessert = this.desserts[this.getRandomDishFromCourse('desserts')];
    return 'Your meal is ' + appetizer.name + ', ' + main.name + ', and ' + dessert.name + '. The total price is $' + /* this.dish.price */ 8 + '.';
  }
};

menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Bread Loaf', 4.25);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Caesar Salad', 3.50);
menu.addDishToCourse('appetizers', 'Small Soup', 4.50);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Steak Dinner', 20.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'spaghetti', 16.00);
menu.addDishToCourse('mains', 'Turkey Dinner', 18.99);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Icecream', 5.99);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Cookies', 5.99);
menu.addDishToCourse('desserts', 'Jello', 5.99);

//console.log(JSON.stringify(menu, null, 4));

console.log(menu.generateRandomMeal());
```